# AppHarbor + Quartz

Tags: c#, .net, scheduler

Tenho uma aplicação no Appharbor (em c#), apenas com 2 botões, um pra iniciar um job e outro para parar o mesmo.

Programei o job para ser executado a cada 15 minutos, e repetir pra sempre (ou até eu forçar a parada), porém, ele não executa a cada 15 minutos.

Iniciei o job as 22:30, ele executou uma vez, depois executou as 22:45, e não executou mais... Mas no localhost ele funciona perfeitamente.

Fiquei me perguntando...
O AppHarbor "hiberna" minha aplicação se não houver acesso por muito tempo?

Fiz seguindo esse tutorial: https://blog.appharbor.com/2012/4/18/scheduled-tasks-using-quartz-and-appharbor-background-workers